# Access variable value by its name as String (groovy)

Tags: groovy, eval

I've done some research but I haven't found a working code for my case. I have two variables named `test` and `test2` and I want to put them in a map in the format `[test:valueof(test), test2:valueof(test2)]`

My piece of code is the following:

```
def test="HELLO"
def test2="WORLD"
def queryText = "\$\$test\$\$ \$\$test2\$\$ this is my test"

def list = queryText.findAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/)

def map = [:]
list.each{
    it = it.replace("\$\$", "")
    map.putAt(it, it)
}

queryText = queryText.replaceAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/) { k -> map[k[1]] ?: k[0] }

System.out.println(map)
System.out.println(queryText)
```

Output:

[image: output]

Desired output:

```
"HELLO WORLD this is my test"
```

I think I need something like `map.putAt(it, eval(it))`

**EDIT**

This is the way I get my inputs. the code goes into the `'test'` script

The ones on the right are the variable names inside the script, the left column are the values (that will later be dynamic)

[image]
[image]

Comment: GiLA3, have you got chance to check the solution?

Comment: What is the data in `RTFTemplates and Message1`? Is your current groovy script in `test`?

Comment: Data in RTF Templates is irrelevant, the `query` attribute is a String with `$$placeholders$$`, message1 is just an empty box where I will return the result `queryText` processed by the script. Yes the script is in `test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.
The solution is instead of putting the values into separate variables put them into the script binding.

Add this at the beginning ( remove the variables `test` and `test2`):

```
def test="HELLO"
def test2="WORLD"
binding.setProperty('test', test)     
binding.setProperty('test2', test2)
```

and change this:

```
{ k -> map[k[1]] ?: k[0] }
```

to this:

```
{ k ->  evaluate(k[1]) }
```

Comment: Variables are already set prior to this piece of code, the `def` part was to make an example, my variables are retrieved as follows: `#input String queryText,test,test2` since I'm using WebRatio. `test` already contains `"HELLO"` and `test2` already contains `"WORLD"`, same goes for `queryText`, so is there a way to adapt the `binding.setProperty` to my situation? Something like `binding.setProperty('test',test)` maybe?

Comment: `{ k ->  evaluate(k[1]) }` was all I needed! `binding` is not needed in my case, even if I don't really understand why. Thanks a lot!

Comment: May be you should accept @dsharew 's answer instead.

Comment: I did it now, is it okay? :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be very simple if you could use `TemplateEngine`.

```
def text = '$test $test2 this is my test'
def binding = [test:'HELLO', test2:'WORLD']
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine() 
def template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)
def result = 'HELLO WORLD this is my test'
assert result == template.toString()
```

You can test quickly online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5128248463720448)</kbd>

Comment: In my requirement I must use my variable names instead of `'HELLO'` and `'WORLD'` since those values change on every execution of the code. I need something like `def binding = [test:valueof(test), test2:valueof(test2)]`

Comment: What is the exact input that you receive? some where there should be mapping / binding of variable and its value, right?

Comment: Edited my question with the information you requested :)

Answer (score 1):

**Final working code, thanks to all, in particular to dsharew who helped me a lot!**

```
#input String queryText,test,test2,test3

def list = queryText.findAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/)

def map = [:]
list.each{
    it = it.replace("\$\$", "")
    map.putAt(it, it)
}

queryText = queryText.replaceAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/) { k ->  evaluate(k[1]) }

return queryText
```